# Difference between std::vector::front() and begin()

Tags: c++, vector, standard-library

Help on `vector` says of `front()`

> Returns a reference to the first element in the vector container.
>    Unlike member `vector::begin`, which returns an iterator to this same element, this >  function returns a direct reference.

Help on vector says of `begin()`

> Returns an iterator referring to the first element in the vector container.
>    Notice that unlike member `vector::front`, which returns a reference to the first element, >  this function returns a random access iterator.

And this code outputs:

```
char arr[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
vector<char> vec(arr, arr+sizeof(arr));
cout << "address of vec.front() " << (void*)&vec.front() << endl;
cout << "address of vec.begin() " << (void*)&vec.begin() << endl;
```

address of `vec.front() 00401F90`
address of `vec.begin() 0030F494`

I don't understand what 'direct reference' means?  In the case of `begin()` isn't a `random access iterator` just a `pointer`?

Can someone please point out the difference?

Comment: `front()` gives you the element (i.e., `'A'`), and `begin()` gives you an iterator that "points" to the first element (so `*begin() == 'A'`).

Comment: Note that `&vec.begin()` is not valid. Your compiler accepts it as an extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In the case of begin() isn't a random access iterator just a pointer?

No, an iterator has some pointer semantics, but it's actually a class.

And even if it was, that should answer the question. It's like asking why the address of a pointer isn't the same as the address of the object it points to.

You'd get the same value if you dereference the iterator, which will give you the first element:

```
&(*vec.begin())
```

because

```
*vec.begin() == vec.front()
```

Comment: Minor correction: In some cases pointers are used as iterators.  std::iterator_traits has a specialization for pointers, and pointers into an array legitimately implement the random access iterator concept.  So, there is a non-empty intersection between the sets of pointers and iterators.  But otherwise, a solid answer.

Answer (score 16):

According to **Stroustrup** in *The C++ Programming Language*, Section 16.3.3; think of `front()` as the first element and `begin()` as a pointer to the first element.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer

Answer (score 4):

For a vector, `begin()` and `end()` return random access iterators. They might return a plain pointer; that's okay, because it meets the requirements to be a random access iterator. In particular, you can write `*begin()` to get a reference to the first object in the sequence (assuming there is one). `front()` gives you a reference to the first object in the sequence, without going through the intermediate iterator. Like this:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(3);
int i = *v.begin(); // i == 3
int j = v.front();  // j == 3
```

Comment: I can see Luchian edited Pete's post.  For the second comment, ITYM `j == 3` (even though the comment shown is still correct, it was quite likely not the one intended).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have at least 1 element in the vector,

```
vec.front()
```

is the same as

```
*vec.begin()
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it clear in your mind, always try to remember the following two lines assuming that you have a vector from STL called `v`:

```
v.front() = * v.begin()
&&
v.back() = * v.end()
```

that means if you have a vector:

```
v = {1,2,3,4};
```

and you have an iterator called IT, and you want to access the first and the last element
you can either do:

```
IT = v.begin();
std::cout<<*IT<<std::endl; // output : 1
IT = v.end();
std::cout<<*IT<<std::endl; // output : 4
```

or you can easily do this:

```
std::cout<<v.front<<std::endl; // output  : 1
std::cout<<v.back<<std::endl; // output  : 4
```

both will print the same output, the difference is just between if you want to use an iterator or not.